# SQL Select To Reference A Lookup Based on Two Columns

Tags: sql-server

I am having quite a hard time getting to build the correct SQL statement for this.

Sample Data (Simplistic View):

```
MasterTable
Product    DebitCode   CreditCode
Camera         1           4
Computer       2           5
Cellphone      3           6


LookupTable
Code    Description
 1      Debit Camera 
 2      Debit Computer 
 3      Debit Cellphone
 4      Credit Camera
 5      Credit Computer
 6      Credit Cellphone
```

I have no problem making an inner join for the DebitCode with the Code in the Lookup table (or the CreditCode) but when I try to use both, I get two entries for each.

I need my data to be retrieved such that the description for both the Debit Code and the Credit Code is all in one row.

Thanks.

Comment: does it make sense to break your lookup table into 2 tables: DebitLookup and CreditLookup?

Comment: In essence, that should be done - break up the lookup into distinct entities.  But since I am working on a singular table of lookup codes, I have no other recourse for now but to reference the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want two separate joins to your LookupTable, one for each code.

```
select mt.Product, 
       lt1.Description as DebitDescription, 
       lt2.Description as CreditDescription
    from MasterTable mt
        inner join LookupTable lt1
            on mt.DebitCode = lt1.Code
        inner join LookupTable lt2
            on mt.CreditCode = lt2.Code
```

Comment: Now I got it. I was only trying to make a join on the same table. Thanks for this tip.